# Increase space in between equations in align environment

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I want to increase the spacing in between certain (not all) equations in an `align` environment. How can that be done?

```
\begin{align}
    x &+ 3
    x + x &+ 3
   %space
    x &+ 3
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting `\\` at the end, I think that the fast solution it put a vertical space `[1em]`, where `1em` it is a measure.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    x &+ 3\\
    x + x &+ 3\\[1em]
   x &+ 3
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer @Sebastiano.

Comment: @NilsK Welcome to the community....and you're welcome :-)